# linq combine model string into single string

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to find a simple way to combine strings from several model into a single string using linq to object expressions.  Trying to put the result either all in first object where bob's name is, or all in People.names location.  Maybe I need to add an another extension method like coalesce?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            People people = new People
            {
                Persons = 
                {
                    new Person{
                        Name = "Bob",
                        Age = 15
                    },
                    new Person{
                        Name = "James",
                        Age = 17
                    },
                    new Person{
                        Name = "Mary",
                        Age = 15
                    }
                },
            };

            people.names = people.Persons.Select(p => p.Name).ToList().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(people.names);

        }
    }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        public class People
        {
            public People() {
                Persons = new List<Person>(); 
            }
            public string names { get; set; }   
            public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        }

}
```

Comment: can't you just have a property called Names with a getter that does something like return String.Join(",", Persons.Select(p => p.Name));

Comment: How do you want these strings delimited?  Commas, spaces?

Comment: a comma and a space

Answer (score 2):

Could do something like this:

```
class People
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public string Names
    {
        get
        {
            if (Persons != null)
            {
                return String.Join(",", Persons.Select(p => p.Name));
            }
            else 
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this would work if Persons was null, `String.Join()` will [throw an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) is the second parameter is null.

Comment: Was just showing how you would do it, edge cases can be implemented by OP

Comment: @austinwenli Just trying to help make your answer more complete and stand out among the competition...  It wouldnt hurt to make it _even better_.  I've already upvoted your answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",people.Persons.Select(p => p.Name)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) to join several strings using a separator. To join the names use a simple select like:

```
string joinedNames = string.Join(",", people.Persons.Select(p => p.Name));
```

Dont't forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: @RetroCoder while this isnt my favorite answer, it 100% will work.  What makes you think its "not working"

Comment: In my version the "people.Select" part doesn't work.  But it does work when I do "people.persons.Select".

Comment: Ah yeah, good eye.  it should be `string.Join(",", people.Persons.Select(p => p.Name));`.

Comment: Correct @RetroCoder - I fixed the solution.

Comment: @RetroCoder wouldnt you rather have this be a property of the `People` class though?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun versions

```
people.Aggregate("", (a, b) => $"{a} {b.Name}").Trim()
string.Concat(people.Select(p => p.Name + " ")).Trim()
```

Crazy version:

```
string.Concat(people.Zip(
                Enumerable.Range(0, people.Count).Select(x => " "),
                (p, s) => p.Name + s)).Trim()
```

Comment: Probably, is there any more ways (even silly) to do this ?